# Node/Express not finding route for Angular http json post (404)

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, http, post

I'm developing a new Angular client which should communicate with my Node/Express server. I'm currently trying to develop the first step aka the login. This should be an http json post. It turns out that every single time I execute that post from the client to the server, the Node/Express server doesn't find the route for my path.

On the console log of the server, for my post json request I find following stacktrace:

```
OPTIONS /api/auth/facebook/mobile 404 274.092 ms - 1980
```

Node/Express side:

My route

```
app.post('/api/auth/facebook/mobile', authenticationHandler.handleFacebookMobileLoginRequest);
```

Body parser for json is defined:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

On the Angular client side, I do:

```
http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'http://192.168.1.101:3000/api/auth/facebook/mobile',
             headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8;' },
             data: {fbToken: authResponse.accessToken}
      })
        .then(function (response) {
 ...
```

Fun facts:

1. Same route works fine when I call it from a Java app or and Android native app, like

   ```
   final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, SERVER_URL + "/api/auth/facebook/mobile", params, jsonRequestListener, errorListener);
   ```
2. On my Angular client, when I change `data` with `params` then it works, the route is found...but I mean that doesn't make any sense. Moreover,  I've got then a problem on the Angular client side, the answer isn't processed respectively the answer never land in the `.then(...` function. Which again works well in other clients.

Anyone got an idea, a clue or should I call Dr. Strange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible browser [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) CORS issue?

Try using [CORS module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) in Node.js server:

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: sweet jesus hell yeah, that was the solution!

Comment: btw. for history purpose, my client is an Angular client build with the Ionic framework, had the problem while starting the query from the iOS emulator