# angular http routing with node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, routes

I'm attempting to access a .json file that contains my portfolio.  I'm running my backend with express js, and trying to access it using angular like so:

```
$http.get("data/items.json")
.success(function(data){
$scope.items = data;
```

I am getting 404 on my backend when i attempt to access the json.

I thought it might be an issue with preflighted cors requests and attempted to implement the solution provided [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34863293/5187199)  I have yet to find a solution.  I'll stay posted.

Comment: try `/data/items.json`

Answer (score 0):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the 
[express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) built-in middleware function in Express.

Let's say all your static content like your json file is in the "public" folder in the root of your application you can serve it like this.

app.use(express.static('public'));

Now you can access the files in that folder like this

http://localhost:3000/items.json